# Computer network by Kurose (top down approach) TDM Circuit switching - conceptual

Tags: networking

This question is from the book computer network (top down approach by Kurose ; section : 1.3.2 Circuit Switching)

Refer this paragraph :
Suppose there are 10 users and that one user suddenly generates one thousand 1,000-bit packets (1,000,000 bits), while other users remain quiescent and do not generate packets. Under TDM circuit switching with 10 slots per frame and each slot consisting of 1,000 bits, the active user can only use its one time slot per frame to transmit data, while the remaining nine time slots in each frame remain idle. It will be **10 seconds** before all of the active user’s one million bits of data has been transmitted

I don’t understand how the author arrived at **10 secs** as the time to transfer the data.

Answer (score 1):

From the context of that section, the link being discussed is one mega bit per second, 1 Mbps = 1,000,000 bits/sec.

```
1,000 bits/pkt * 1,000 pkts = 1,000,000 bits
1 active slot / 10 slots/frame = 1/10 frame active
1 Mbps * 1/10 active = 100,000 bits/sec
1000000 bits / 100000 bits/sec = 10 secs
```

Comment: To learn TDM, I'd suggest studying real implementations: T1, T3, E1, E3, and J1, J3, and then on to SONET and then on to carrier Ethernet (10G) (modern era).